# can't find any solution for running f2py correctly on my windows 7 machine

Tags: f2py

Can someone pinpoint where I'm doing wrong, PLEASE?   I'm so exhausted.  I installed MinGW 4.7, python2.7.8, numpy 1.7.1 and scipy0.13.2 to an Anaconda (32bit) environment in Windows7.
Also, for user enviroment variables, I set

C_INCLUDE_PATH:
D:\Anaconda2\envs\arc103\MinGW\i686-w64-mingw32\include

Path (User variable):
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS code\bin;D:\Anaconda2\Library\bin;D:\Anaconda2\envs\arc103\MinGW\bin

Tying the following commands in Anaconda Prompt

1. "f2py -c --help-fcompiler" outputs "... Fortran compilers found:
   --fcompiler=gnu95  GNU Fortran 95 compiler (4.7.0) ...."
2. "f2py -c --help-compiler" outputs
   "List of available compilers: ...", not specifically compilers found though.

Running "f2py -c fib1.f -m fib1" according to "NumPy v1.12.dev0 Manual" gives me lots of error as below:

```
D:\Anaconda2\envs\arc103\Scripts\gfortran.bat -Wall -Wall -shared c:\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\Release\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\src.win32-.7\fib1module.oc:\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\Release\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\src.win32-2.7\fortranobject.o c:\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\Release\fib1.o -Ld:\anaconda2\envs\arc103\mingw\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.7.0 -LD:\Anaconda2\envs\arc103\libs -LD:\Anaconda2\envs\arc103\PCbuild -lpython27 -lgfortran -o .\fib1.pyd

c:\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\Release\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\src.win32-2.7\fib1module.o:fib1module.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `__imp__PyNumber_Int'
c:\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\Release\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\src.win32-2.7\fib1module.o:fib1module.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `__imp__PyComplex_Type'
c:\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\Release\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\src.win32-2.7\fib1module.o:fib1module.c:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `__imp__PyType_IsSubtype'
c:\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\Release\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\src.win32-2.7\fib1module.o:fib1module.c:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `__imp__PyErr_Occurred'

...  (Thousands of "undefined reference to" errors I didn't put it here) ...

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit statuserror: Command "D:\Anaconda2\envs\arc103\Scripts\gfortran.bat -Wall -Wall -shared c:\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\Release\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\src.win32-2.7\fib1module.o
c:\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\Release\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\src.win32-2.7\fortranobject.o 
c:\users\dkim1\appdata\local\temp\tmpvyedhg\Release\fib1.o -Ld:\anaconda2\envs\arc103\mingw\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.7.0 -LD:\Anaconda2\envs\arc103\libs
-LD:\Anaconda2\envs\arc103\PCbuild -lpython27 -lgfortran -o .\fib1.pyd" failed with exit status 1
```

Sorry for the mess.  I have spent almost a few months finding out the fix, but it's too hard for me and all gone to no avail.  It would be hugely appreciated if you can help me out.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the full output.? (without all the "undefined reference to" errors of course)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a couple month old, I am not sure if these tips will still help, but I found when building a Fortran to Python module on Win 10, that only compiling for 32bit worked, and you need to use a signature file, i.e. something along the lines of:

```
f2py.py -c cuncsd.pyf cuncsd.f
```

Instead of using the i686-w64-mingw32 toolchain I used a straight [mingw32](https://pilotfiber.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mingw/Installer/mingw-get-setup.exe) one (to reduce the risk that I accidentally end up with anything 64bit).

I also found that you need to install a special Visual Studio for Python instance as described here:
[Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909330/microsoft-visual-c-compiler-for-python-3-4)

If you are using Python 2.7 this VSC version should do the trick for you, only newer version (3.5, 3.6) are left out at this time.

For reference here is my complete f2py invocation on the console that I ended up using (neither python nor f2py were on the execution PATH):

```
python C:\Python34\Scripts\f2py.py -c cuncsd.pyf --opt="-frecursive -fmax-stack-var-size=66560" cuncsd.f -llapack -lrefblas -ltmglib
```

This particular module depends on 32 bit LAPCK shared libraries that I compiled previously, and we found it even works on XP systems.

I later went back and tried to compile this for 64 bit, but eventually gave up, when I always encountered ld errors.  I think going forward for Windows 10 it will be much easier to use the embedded Ubuntu to execute and extend Python.

(See [How to enable Bash in Windows 10 developer preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352627/how-to-enable-bash-in-windows-10-developer-preview) and [Getting PyCharm to recognize python on the windows linux subsystem (bash on windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000166/getting-pycharm-to-recognize-python-on-the-windows-linux-subsystem-bash-on-wind))