# How to debug a library python script invoked by a bash script in WSL ubuntu using PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Perhaps the problem I'm facing is a little complex, let me try to clarify it.

Currently I have a virtualenv installed in my WSL ubuntu. In this env, I installed a python package using pip. This package provides some convenient cli-interface commands, so if I have activated the env, I can directly run some commands like

```
(myEnv) name@host: py_cli_cmd --option1 aa --option2 bb ...
```

Now I have a bash script, defined some variables and invoked the python commands several times, structure like

```sh
base_dir=data/
first_dir=$base_dir/first/
second_dir=$base_dir/second/
...
for choice in a b
do
  py_cli_cmd --option1 $choice --option2 $first_dir
done
```

Now I want to understand the data flow and data structures of the python command, so I planned to use PyCharm to debug it. However I'm facing two problems:

- I modified the python scripts in pycharm, added some print statements, but seems they took no effect
- I tried to attach pycharm to the process running in the WSL, but the IDE prompted no processes were found

In such a case can I have any way to debug the python script? Thank you all.

Comment: see if this may [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000166/getting-pycharm-to-recognize-python-on-the-windows-linux-subsystem-bash-on-wind)

Comment: @sahasrara62 Perhaps I didn't quite get your point. I can setup the python interpreter in Pycharm, making it to point to a virtualenv in the WSL (I think this is what the link you provide is for), but my Pycharm cannot be attached to a python process running in the WSL

Comment: you need to setup the ssh tool in pycharm, through ssh you can see the live result of your batch script, seeing live result on terminal is in not possible ( i think), so to solve problem, use logging, and after completion of code see what went wring in log file